# Django - QuerySet to multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Fixture(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="home")
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="away")
    game_week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2, default=0)
```

What I want to do is create a multi-dimensional list that groups all of my fixture objects by the 'game_week' property. For example:

```
   fixtures[0] = [<FixtureObject 1>, <FixtureObject 2>]
   fixtures[1] = [<FixtureObject 3>, <FixtureObject 4>]
   fixtures[2] = [<FixtureObject 5>]
   fixtures[3] = [<FixtureObject 6>]
```

Where the fixture list indexes are the different game weeks. What is the easiest, most pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is to use a dictionary:

```
 fixtures = Fixture.objects.all()
 fixture_dict = {}
 for fixture in fixtures:
    fixture_dict.setdefault(fixture.game_week, []).append(fixture)
```